# Losing precision with floating point numbers (double) in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

I'm trying to assign a big `double` value to a variable and print it on the console. The number I supply in is different than what is displayed as output. Is it possible to get the `double` value correctly assigned and output without the loss of precision? Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    // turn off scientific notation on floating point numbers
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 3 );

    // maximum double value on my machine
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << std::endl;

    // string representation of the double value I want to get
    std::cout << "123456789123456789123456789123456789.01" << std::endl;

    // value I supplied        
    double d = 123456789123456789123456789123456789.01;

    // it's printing 123456789123456784102659645885120512.000 instead of 123456789123456789123456789123456789.01
    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Could you, please, help me to understand the problem.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: as a rule of thumb, `double` is only precise to about 15 decimal places (53 binary places).

Comment: @Zinki 17 digits is the maximum precision. Writing out a `double` with precision 17 guarantees you'll get the same binary representation when parsed.

Comment: @Angew You are both right. Starting from a given `double`, one needs to print 17 significant digits if one wants to be sure to parse back the same `double`. Starting from a decimal representation, only 15 decimal digits are guaranteed to be the same when printing the `double` parsed from the decimal representation. There is no “maximum precision” in any meaningful sense : If you want to represent exactly the 700 or so decimal digits of 2^-1000, you are in luck, because this number with 700 significant digits in decimal is represented exactly as a `double`, so the “maximum precision” is 700ish.

Comment: Please note that `std::setprecision` does not in any way modify the actual precision of a built in type `double`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yeah, I know about the string->double->string vs. double->string->double difference, but it's generally easier to remember just one number, and it makes sense to use the higher one. And I meant "maximum" as in "maximum independent of the value."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ built-in floating point types are finite in precision. `double` is usually implemented as [IEEE-754 double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), meaning it has 53 bits of mantissa (the "value") precision, 11 bits of exponent precision, and 1 sign bit.

The number 123456789123456789123456789123456789 requires way more than 53 bits to represent, meaning a typical `double` cannot possibly represent it accurately. If you want such large numbers with perfect precision, you need to use some sort of a "big number" library.

For more information on floating point formats and their inaccuracies, you can read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: I think I will have to use a library to get the precision I want. Anyway, many thanks everyone for effort.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, fixed.