# Why C++ double giving wrong answer for Just 17 DIGITS?

Tags: c++, double

Recently while practicing I found this problem, Please run this code in your local machine.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
double power(double a, double b) {
    double ans = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= b; i++){
        ans *= a;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    double anaconda = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        anaconda += power(10,i);
        cout << setprecision(30) << fixed <<i << " "<< anaconda << endl;
    }
}
```

If you run this code you should see something like this

[image: output]

Your can also see this code running in IDEONE
You can see there from i = 16 , the program is giving wrong output.
There should be all 1s in every number.
Can anyone please tell me

- Why this is giving wrong result even in this small range ?
- And how to avoid this type of calculation problem ?
  Thanks in advance ❤️❤️❤️

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10` is `15`. Your range is not "small". You need to use a wider type, do you really need more than 15 significant digits?

Comment: btw calling `power(10,i)` in each iteration is a waste of cpu. You only need to multiply `10` in each iteration instead of starting from `1` every time

Comment: A `double` has only 15 digits of decimal precision - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64 - setting the display precision doesn't affect the internal representation.

Comment: to get higher precision, use a third party library for high precision math

Comment: Ashiqur Rahman "There should be all 1s in every number. " makes sense if `double` could encode **every** number.  As a 64-bit floating point number, only about 2^64 numbers are encodeable. Something has to give.

Comment: duplicates: [Why IEEE754 single-precision float has only 7 digit precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19130396/995714), [Double precision - decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9999221/995714), [Precision loss with double C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12096852/995714), [Losing precision with floating point numbers (double) in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48148235/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ double type is typically stored (in memory) in 64-bit "double-precision floating-point" format.

While this allows you to represent and calculate on both very large, and very small, numbers (relative to other common c++ datatypes) it only does this with a certain **precision**.

This means that you can only rely on 15-17 digits being exact. Anything beyond that is the result of rounding to the nearest value that can be represented in the specific amount of memory (again, typically 64-bits).

I hope this answers the first question. There's much more to learn about this, for example in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

As for the second question, the answer is that it depends. It depends on just *how big* the numbers you want to represent are.

For example, if you are just working with positive integers, you can extend the range somewhat by switching to `unsigned long long int` which get's you to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (not quite enough for the code at hand, so I'm mostly mentioning it for completeness).

If that's not sufficient you probably want to be looking for a c++ library for big numbers.

Google `c++ big number library` and/or `c++ big integer library`.

Comment: Thank you so much ❤️❤️❤️. The concept is now clear to me . ❤️